# using firefox to launch an external program found in the system PATH

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

i have an addon that i want to use to start program already installed on my computer eg notepad.exe

**The problem** is that it seems firefox does not search the system PATH for the program ie

```
        file.initWithPath("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");//works
    //file.initWithPath("notepad.exe");//does not work
        //file.initWithPath("%systemroot%\\notepad.exe");//does not work
```

**Question:**
Is there a way of making firefox look for programs in the system PATH?
Here is my complete function

```
autoStartNotepad:function()
{
    // create an nsILocalFile for the executable
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath("notepad.exe");//does not work
    //but file.initWithPath("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");//works

    // create an nsIProcess
    var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    process.init(file);

    // Run the process.
    // If first param is true, calling thread will be blocked until
    // called process terminates.
    // Second and third params are used to pass command-line arguments
    // to the process.
    var args = [];
    process.run(false, args, args.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nsIProcess` won't do this, it only accepts full paths. You will need to take a look at environment variables yourself:

```
var environment = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
var path = environment.get("PATH");
var root = environment.get("SYSTEMROOT");
```

You can either split up the `PATH` variable and check the various directories or use the value of the `SYSTEMROOT` variable.

You could run `cmd.exe /c notepad.exe` but there you also need to locate `cmd.exe` first.